# How to refer the current namespace for the service account in rolebinding yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

Having a rolebinding with a serviceaccount on the same namespace as subject. Is it possible to specify the current namespace through reference. Something simillar to setting env from fieldreference in containers and using them without hardcoding it multiple places.

```
    env:
    - name: NS
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

The rolebinding yaml is given below, Is it possible to avoid the *mynamespace* in the subject with some kind of reference to the current namespace `.metadata.namespace`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
  namespace: mynamespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: reader-service
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: default
```

Comment: Yes, As you mentioned we can create an environment variable and use it for namespace in subject without hardcoding it multiple places.  
I have tested it in my environment and it worked for me. Refer to this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) for more information.

Comment: @GoliNikitha env is valid unders the containers, is it still valid here?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating env variable in the yaml of role binding and that worked. I was able to use that env variable in another yaml files.

Comment: @GoliNikitha can you add an example here

Answer (score -1):

I have added environment variables to the First role binding config file and used this environment variable in the Second role binding config file and  the role binding was  successful.

**First role binding config file:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
 name: pod-reader
 namespace: mynamespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: reader-service
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

**Second role binding config file:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-reader1
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: reader-service
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: MY_POD_NAMESPACES
  name: default
```

Comment: I feel the `spec.containers` in the role binding config does not really belong there as it seems to belong to a deployment config, doesn't it? https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/ does not mention this.

Comment: And moreover my requirement was to refer metadata.namespace for subject.namespace on the same file. Not two different files